# How to populate drop down list selected for search record using stored procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net, stored-procedures

I am newbie on asp.net c#. How to show record when drop down list selected by user using stored procedure with C# code. Can anyone give me some example of this? Thank you

Below my code :

```
<div id="divStatus">
<center style="height: 489px; width: 768px">
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="lblHead" runat="server" Text="Call Status Report" 
        style="font-weight: 700"></asp:Label>
    <br />
<br /> 
<table style="width: 250px">
<tr>
<td>Select Employee</td>
<td><asp:DropDownList ID="ddlEmp" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList></td>
<td><asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvEmp" runat="server" ControlToValidate="ddlEmp" ErrorMessage="*"  ></asp:RequiredFieldValidator></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td  colspan="2"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td style="margin-left: 40px">
    <asp:Button ID="btnStatus" runat="server" 
        Text="Status" Width="71px" onclick="btnStatus_Click" />
        </td>
</tr>
</table>
<br />
<br />
<asp:GridView ID="gvStatus" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        onpageindexchanging="gvStatus_PageIndexChanging" Width="464px">
<Columns>
<asp:BoundField DataField="Call_logID" HeaderText="Log ID" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="EntryTime" HeaderText="DateIn" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="Log_Status" HeaderText="Status" />
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

below its my Store procedure:

```
@Log_EntryBy varchar(100) = ''
AS

select CONVERT (varchar(50),EntryTime,103)as Date, Call_logID,Log_code , Log_Status from Call_Log_Service
where Log_EntryBy = @Log_EntryBy order by Call_logID
```

Comment: put C# code here. What you have tried

Answer (score 0):

Hello this is a simple example of dropdown list

My source code is like this

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
   <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListTest" runat="server" 
        onselectedindexchanged="DropDownListTest_SelectedIndexChanged" 
        AutoPostBack="True">
       <asp:ListItem Value="0">Select</asp:ListItem>
       <asp:ListItem Value="1">Super admin</asp:ListItem>
       <asp:ListItem Value="2">Admin</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList> 

<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" >Hello</asp:Label>
</div>

</form>
```

**On .cs file**

```
 protected void DropDownListTest_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Label1.Text = DropDownListTest.SelectedItem.Value;
    }
```

I am changing the label value with drop down selected value
I hope this example will help u

Comment: how about if i using SP? I want to filter search my record based on  my drop down list?

Comment: try this:int RID=Convert.ToInt32(DropDownListTest.SelectedItem.Value); string ConnectionString = @"Write your connection string here";
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand();
            con.Open();
            com.Connection = con;
            com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            com.CommandText = "SP_Testing";
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id",RID);
            SqlDataReader dr;
            dr = com.ExecuteReader();

Comment: SP_Testing is My stored procedure which filtered the records based on dropdown id

Answer (score 0):

To give a more accurate answer, you would need to provide the stored procedure name and what it outputs. Without those details, I'm making the following assumptions which you'll have to adjust to your actual environment.

1. Stored Procedure to call: `Employees_Select`
2. The procedure returns a single result set with field names `FullName` and `EmployeeId`

First, you'll need to configure your dropdown to map to the fields of the data source:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlEmp" runat="server" DataTextField="FullName" DataValueField="EmployeeId"></asp:DropDownList>
```

And then, you'll need to have code called when the form is loaded (or whatever even you think is needed) to bind to dropdown.

```
    protected void FillEmployees()
    {
        var connectionString = "your_connection_string_from_config";
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            using (var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("Employees_Select", connection))
            {
                connection.Open();
                adapter.SelectCommand.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                var ds = new System.Data.DataSet();
                adapter.Fill(ds);
                ddlEmp.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
                ddlEmp.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: hi Jason thanks for the good code. here its my SP. Isn't correct?

Comment: Can you add the SP that provides the list of employees? The SP you provided seems to be your call log history that you would want to populate your datagrid.

Comment: select CONVERT (varchar(50),EntryTime,103)as Date, Call_logID,Log_code , Log_Status from Call_Log_Service
where Log_EntryBy = @Log_EntryBy order by Call_logID

Comment: isn't correct the SP? or i need change it to if statement? I want to filter based on call receive status by log entry(employee).hope u can help me out

Comment: I currently understand your question to be how to populate your dropdown from the database. Based on your aspx, it appears you need the list of employees with a full name (for the dropdown text) and a id (as the dropdown option value so that you provide as a parameter to the SP you provided for @Log_EntryBy)

Comment: correct sir. but how to bind my data based on drop down list selected?